# Build variable into python zip script

Tags: python, zip, archive

Before I start, I am trying to create a python zip script which will take a snapshot of the target_dir, zip it, save it in the temp folder and give it the filename of "now" variable. This is the code I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
target_dir = '/var/lib/data'
temp_dir='/tmp'

zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/example.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
rootlen = len(target_dir) + 1
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
   for file in files:
      fn = os.path.join(base, file)
      zip.write(fn, fn[rootlen:])
```

I can't figure out how to get this line to instead use the variable "now" and "temp_dir" instead of hardcoding the destination:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/example.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

I guess I want something like this (pseudo code):

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('<temp_dir>/<now>.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Can anyone show me how this should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python string formating lets you put the content of variables into strings, that would be

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('%s/%s.zip' % (temp_dir, now), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

String formating replaces the occurences of "%s" with the strings in the tuple after the formating operator `%`.

Alternatively (and cleaner), use the same `os.path.join` you use later in your code:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(temp_dir, now+".zip"), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

os.path.join is a function that glues together elements of a file system path according to whatever logic your file system uses, so it would use `\` instead of `/` in operating systems that use that character in paths. String concatenation is just `+`, so to glue the file ending `.zip` to another string `now`, `now+".zip"` just does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In short, `os.path.join(temp_dir, now + '.zip')`, but I'm not sure if that's really what you're asking. Because I'm not sure how you could have gotten as far as you have and gotten stuck here.

Comment: I have been trying to build on other peoples example code so I cant claim most of this, I am trying to make it work for my application.

Comment: I have tried to implement your code, can you please just see if I have done it correctly? https://gist.github.com/4114493

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the higher-level function within [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html):

```
>>> import shutil
>>> from time import strftime
>>> now = strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
>>> shutil.make_archive('/tmp/file_%s' % now, 'zip', '/usr/games/')
'/tmp/file_2012-11-19_22-43.zip'
```